# "Better than nothing"

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, usage, expressions-idiomatiques

> If you say that something is better than nothing, you mean that it is
>   not what is required, but that it is better to have that thing than to
>   have nothing at all.
>
> E.g. After all, 15 minutes of exercise is better than nothing.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-better-than-nothing

> Après tout, 15 minutes d’exercice valent mieux que rien.

*qqch vaut mieux que rien* est-il utilisé en français comme *sth is better than nothing* en anglais ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, cela s'utilise ; on dit (et on écrit) couramment  « **Ça vaut mieux que rien** » et  « **Ç'est mieux que rien** ».

Où en anglais on dit « **It sounds better than nothing.** » on peut traduire par « **Ça a l'air d'être mieux que rien.** » (et vice versa, bien sûr).

Comment: Merci toujours :-)!